# Installing Jekyll on Mac OS Leopard (10.5.8)

Tags: ruby, jekyll, homebrew, rvm

I'm trying to install Jekyll on Leopard but can't get it working. The most progress I've made is being able to run `gem install jekyll` in Terminal, but then I get the error `make failed, exit code 2`.

- I have tigerbrew installed (since brew is incompatible with leopard now)
- I have rvm installed (installed from source due to constant certificate/ssl errors)
- I have installed Ruby version 2.3.8p459 from source
- I have Xcode 3.1.3 installed

I can't install ruby from rbenv or rvm due to cert/ssl errors, that's why I've installed it from source. I can install via `brew install ruby`, but get the same results.

I've looked at many other posts regarding the `make failed` error which tends to be related to multiple Ruby versions. None of the answers on these pages worked as I've installed everything from source (ruby has never been installed by brew, rbenv or rvm).
I have tried installing ruby with all of the above but got the same error.
Each time I've tested installing Ruby either from source or from tigerbrew/homebrew I've clean installed a new system of Leopard + Xcode etc. I've also tried this on multiple machines.

I've just updated rubygems to version 3.0.2, which fixed some certificate errors when installing gems but hasn't fixed the problem.

Is there anything else I can do to get this working??

Below is the output from Terminal when I run `gem install jekyll`.

```
jordans-power-mac-g4:desktop Jordan$ gem 

install jekyll
Fetching fast-stemmer-1.0.2.gem
Fetching sass-3.7.2.gem
Fetching ruby_dep-1.5.0.gem
Fetching coffee-script-source-1.11.1.gem
Fetching rb-fsevent-0.10.3.gem
Fetching rb-inotify-0.10.0.gem
Fetching jekyll-watch-1.5.1.gem
Fetching ffi-1.9.25.gem
Fetching coffee-script-2.4.1.gem
Fetching public_suffix-3.0.3.gem
Fetching sass-listen-4.0.0.gem
Fetching faraday-0.15.4.gem
Fetching listen-3.1.5.gem
Fetching jekyll-gist-1.5.0.gem
Fetching execjs-2.7.0.gem
Fetching blankslate-2.1.2.4.gem
Fetching parslet-1.5.0.gem
Fetching multipart-post-2.0.0.gem
Fetching jekyll-sass-converter-1.5.2.gem
Fetching yajl-ruby-1.2.3.gem
Fetching toml-0.1.2.gem
Fetching redcarpet-3.4.0.gem
Fetching octokit-4.13.0.gem
Fetching posix-spawn-0.3.13.gem
Fetching pygments.rb-0.6.3.gem
Fetching colorator-0.1.gem
Fetching liquid-2.6.3.gem
Fetching jekyll-paginate-1.1.0.gem
Fetching mercenary-0.3.6.gem
Fetching jekyll-coffeescript-1.1.1.gem
Fetching addressable-2.5.2.gem
Fetching sawyer-0.8.1.gem
Fetching kramdown-1.17.0.gem
Fetching safe_yaml-1.0.4.gem
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed fast-stemmer-1.0.2
Successfully installed classifier-reborn-2.2.0
Successfully installed rb-fsevent-0.10.3
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-

1.9.25/ext/ffi_c
    /usr/local/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0 -r ./siteconf20190101-36895-fo3oja.rb extconf.rb
    checking for ffi.h... no
    checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi... yes
    checking for ffi_call() in -lffi... yes
    checking for ffi_closure_alloc()... no
    checking for ffi_raw_call()... no
    checking for shlwapi.h... no
    checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
    checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
    checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
    checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
    creating extconf.h
    creating Makefile

    current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c
    make "DESTDIR=" clean

    current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c
    make "DESTDIR="
    Configuring libffi
    cd "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi-powerpc-darwin9.0" && make
    make 'AR_FLAGS=' 'CC_FOR_BUILD=' 'CFLAGS=-Wall -fexceptions' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2' 'CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=' 'CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=' 'INSTALL=/usr/local/bin/ginstall -c' 'INSTALL_DATA=/usr/local/bin/ginstall -c -m 644' 'INSTALL_PROGRAM=/usr/local/bin/ginstall -c' 'INSTALL_SCRIPT=/usr/local/bin/ginstall -c' 'JC1FLAGS=' 'LDFLAGS=' 'LIBCFLAGS=' 'LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=' 'MAKE=make' 'MAKEINFO=/bin/sh /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/missing makeinfo ' 'PICFLAG=' 'PICFLAG_FOR_TARGET=' 'RUNTESTFLAGS=' 'SHELL=/bin/sh' 'exec_prefix=/usr/local' 'infodir=/usr/local/share/info' 'libdir=/usr/local/lib' 'mandir=/usr/local/share/man' 'prefix=/usr/local' 'AR=ar' 'AS=as' 'CC=gcc' 'CXX=g++' 'LD=ld' 'NM=/usr/bin/nm -p' 'RANLIB=ranlib' 'DESTDIR=' all-recursive
    Making all in include
    make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
    Making all in testsuite
    make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
    Making all in man
    make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
    /bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi  -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src   -Wall -fexceptions -c -o src/prep_cif.lo /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/prep_cif.c
    libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src -Wall -fexceptions -c /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/prep_cif.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o src/.libs/prep_cif.o
    /bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi  -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src   -Wall -fexceptions -c -o src/types.lo /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/types.c
    libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src -Wall -fexceptions -c /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/types.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o src/.libs/types.o
    /bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi  -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src   -Wall -fexceptions -c -o src/raw_api.lo /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/raw_api.c
    libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src -Wall -fexceptions -c /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/raw_api.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o src/.libs/raw_api.o
    /bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi  -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src   -Wall -fexceptions -c -o src/java_raw_api.lo /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/java_raw_api.c
    libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src -Wall -fexceptions -c /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/java_raw_api.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o src/.libs/java_raw_api.o
    /bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi  -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src   -Wall -fexceptions -c -o src/closures.lo /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/closures.c
    libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src -Wall -fexceptions -c /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/closures.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o src/.libs/closures.o
    /bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi  -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src   -Wall -fexceptions -c -o src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.lo /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c
    libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src -Wall -fexceptions -c /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o src/powerpc/.libs/ffi_darwin.o
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1114: error: syntax error before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1116: error: syntax error before ‘)’ token
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1172: error: syntax error before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1434: error: syntax error before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c: In function ‘ffi_go_closure_helper_DARWIN’:
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1437: error: ‘closure’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1437: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1437: error: for each function it appears in.)
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1438: error: ‘rvalue’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1438: error: ‘pgr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1438: error: ‘pfr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    make[3]: *** [src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.lo] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
    make: *** ["/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi-powerpc-darwin9.0"/.libs/libffi_convenience.a] Error 2

    make failed, exit code 2

    Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25 for inspection.
    Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/powerpc-darwin-9/2.3.0-static/ffi-1.9.25/gem_make.out
```

Edit:

Also tried with fresh OS install, Ruby 1.9.3p0, and Jekyll 2.0.2. Output results below.

```
    powerbook:~ Jordan$ sudo gem install jekyll -v 2.0.2
Fetching: liquid-2.5.5.gem (100%)
Fetching: fast-stemmer-1.0.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Fetching: mathn-0.1.0.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Fetching: classifier-1.3.5.gem (100%)
Fetching: hitimes-1.3.0.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Fetching: timers-4.0.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: celluloid-0.16.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: rb-fsevent-0.10.3.gem (100%)
Fetching: ffi-1.9.25.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... no
checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi... yes
checking for ffi_call() in -lffi... yes
checking for ffi_closure_alloc()... no
checking for ffi_raw_call()... no
checking for shlwapi.h... no
checking for ruby/thread.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make
Configuring libffi
cd "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi-powerpc-darwin9.6.0" && make
make 'AR_FLAGS=' 'CC_FOR_BUILD=' 'CFLAGS=-Wall -fexceptions' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2' 'CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=' 'CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=' 'INSTALL=/usr/bin/install -c' 'INSTALL_DATA=/usr/bin/install -c -m 644' 'INSTALL_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/install -c' 'INSTALL_SCRIPT=/usr/bin/install -c' 'JC1FLAGS=' 'LDFLAGS=' 'LIBCFLAGS=' 'LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=' 'MAKE=make' 'MAKEINFO=/bin/sh /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/missing makeinfo ' 'PICFLAG=' 'PICFLAG_FOR_TARGET=' 'RUNTESTFLAGS=' 'SHELL=/bin/sh' 'exec_prefix=/usr/local' 'infodir=/usr/local/share/info' 'libdir=/usr/local/lib' 'mandir=/usr/local/share/man' 'prefix=/usr/local' 'AR=ar' 'AS=as' 'CC=gcc' 'CXX=g++' 'LD=ld' 'NM=/usr/bin/nm -p' 'RANLIB=ranlib' 'DESTDIR=' all-recursive
Making all in include
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in testsuite
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in man
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi  -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src   -Wall -fexceptions -c -o src/prep_cif.lo /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/prep_cif.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src -Wall -fexceptions -c /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/prep_cif.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o src/.libs/prep_cif.o
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi  -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src   -Wall -fexceptions -c -o src/types.lo /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/types.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src -Wall -fexceptions -c /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/types.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o src/.libs/types.o
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi  -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src   -Wall -fexceptions -c -o src/raw_api.lo /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/raw_api.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src -Wall -fexceptions -c /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/raw_api.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o src/.libs/raw_api.o
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi  -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src   -Wall -fexceptions -c -o src/java_raw_api.lo /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/java_raw_api.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src -Wall -fexceptions -c /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/java_raw_api.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o src/.libs/java_raw_api.o
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi  -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src   -Wall -fexceptions -c -o src/closures.lo /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/closures.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src -Wall -fexceptions -c /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/closures.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o src/.libs/closures.o
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi  -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src   -Wall -fexceptions -c -o src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.lo /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi -I. -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src -Wall -fexceptions -c /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o src/powerpc/.libs/ffi_darwin.o
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1114: error: syntax error before ‘*’ token
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1116: error: syntax error before ‘)’ token
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1172: error: syntax error before ‘*’ token
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1434: error: syntax error before ‘*’ token
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c: In function ‘ffi_go_closure_helper_DARWIN’:
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1437: error: ‘closure’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1437: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1437: error: for each function it appears in.)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1438: error: ‘rvalue’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1438: error: ‘pgr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi/src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.c:1438: error: ‘pfr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make[3]: *** [src/powerpc/ffi_darwin.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** ["/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/libffi-powerpc-darwin9.6.0"/.libs/libffi_convenience.a] Error 2


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
```

Comment: What if you try Ruby 1.9.3 (the oldest version I'd recommend and closer to your OS release date) and jekyll 2.5.3 (the last version to support Ruby 1.9.3)? Your OS is 11 years old, you may have to make do with older versions of these as well.

Comment: That doesn't work either, see the above edit. Even tried with Jekyll 1.0.0

Comment: Any help from [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42243)? This is a tough problem, and before spending too much time on resolving it I'd seriously consider finding a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that the Make error is due to some dependencies being incompatible with the system.

I managed to get Jekyll 3.8.5 installed on OSX 10.5.6 (Leopard) by running these commands:

```
sudo gem install ffi -v 1.7.0

sudo gem install eventmachine -v 1.0.9.1

sudo gem install jekyll -v 3.8.5
```

Now to try 10.4.8..